# Facebook OGP image not working in timeline

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like, facebook-timeline

Facebook is not displaying correct image on my timeline when I've liked a page on my website.

[image]

HOWEVER, It works perfectly in the newsfeed.

The Facebook Debugger returns
[no errors](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http://www.evently.no/e.php?eid=11264)

And, if I share the link, it also works perfectly

[image]

Does anyone have a solution to this problem?